# Purging Just Exceptions from Oracle Advanced Queue

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to purge the exceptions and only the exceptions from an Oracle Advanced Queue. This is what I have.

```
DECLARE
    purge_options dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;
BEGIN
  DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE(
    queue_table => 'HOLONET_Q_TAB',
    purge_condition => 'Q_NAME = ''AQ$_HOLONET_Q_TAB_E''',
    purge_options   => purge_options
  );
END;
```

However, this code is producing the following error.

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM", line 2093
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYS", line 16139
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYS", line 16355
ORA-00904: "Q_NAME": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQ_INV", line 1573
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYSCALLS", line 1113
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYS", line 16326
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYS", line 16127
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM", line 2086
ORA-06512: at line 4
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to figure it out. The correct code is as follows:

```
DECLARE
    purge_options dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;
BEGIN
  DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE(
    queue_table => 'HOLONET_Q_TAB',
    purge_condition => 'qtview.QUEUE = ''AQ$_HOLONET_Q_TAB_E''',
    purge_options   => purge_options
  );
END;
```